# Probability that value chosen by first person is less than the second person

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I have two people. The first person can choose a number from $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, and the second person can choose a number from $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$.There is a  condition that the second person shouldn't choose the $5$.

> What is the probability that the number that is chosen by the first person is less than the number chosen by the second person ?

Choosing $0, 1, 2, 3$ from the set $1$ has probability $0.25$ (each value is equal). The same applies for set $2$, choosing a number from set $2$ has the same probability for each value $(0.125)$.

What I tried is the following:

(Person 1 chooses 0) * (Person 2 chooses 1) + (Person 1 chooses 0) * (Person 2 chooses 2) + (Person 1 chooses 0) * (Person 2 chooses 3) + (Person 1 chooses 0) * (Person 2 chooses 4) + (Person 1 chooses 0) * (Person 2 chooses 6) +
(Person 1 chooses 0) * (Person 2 chooses 7) + (Person 1 chooses 1) * (Person 2 chooses 2) + ...  + (Person 1 chooses 1) * (Person 2 chooses 7) + (Person 1 chooses 2) * (Person 2 chooses 3) + (Person 1 chooses 2) * (Person 2 chooses 6) + (Person 1 chooses 2) * (Person 2 chooses 7) + (Person 1 chooses 3) * (Person 2 chooses 4) + (Person 1 chooses 3) * (Person 2 chooses 6) + (Person 1 chooses 3) * (Person 2 chooses 7) = $\color{blue}{0.5625}$

Do you think this equation is correct? If not, why? and what should be the correct formulation?

Comment: What you did is effectively brute force and was the long way of doing this.  See if you can spot patterns instead.  "*There is one condition that the second person can't choose 5*"  I don't understand this sentence.  Do you mean to say "What is the probability that the first person's value is less than the second person's *and that the second person didn't choose a 5*?"  Or do you mean to say that the second person chooses equally from $\{0,1,2,3,4,6,7\}$, each being chosen with probability $\frac{1}{7}$ (*and not $\frac{1}{8}$ as it appears in your calculations*)

Comment: Do the persons choose the numbers randomly (in the sense that every choice has equal probability) ? And if $5$ is forbidden, why not just say that the person chooses from $[0,1,2,3,4,6,7]$ ?

Comment: I want the second person not to choose 5, the second person can still choose 5, however, I want the value chosen by the first person to be less than the value chosen by the second person and the second person don't choose a 5.

Comment: 5 is not forbidden, sorry for the misunderstanding instead of 'can't' I should have written 'shouldn't'

Comment: So, you want the CONDITIONAL probability assuming that the choice of person $2$ is not $5$ ?

Comment: Yes, it should be conditional probability I guess...

Comment: Your question needs to state that clearly.

Comment: @Peter I do not read it as a conditional probability.  This is a probability of an intersection of events.  "First smaller *and* second not 5"... This isn't "First smaller *given* second not 5."  Those are very different questions.

Comment: @MathLover then don't solve it :)

Comment: Responding to the comment of @MathLover by : "then don't solve it" is not recommended at mathSE.  I recognize that editing your question to make it impossible for anyone to be confused what you are asking can be very challenging.  Besides possible language difficulties, if this is a problem that you have originated, it can be challenging to translate your intent into very clear (i.e. totally unambiguous) language.  However, going forward for your future mathSE postings, I would encourage you to make more of an effort to make it impossible for a mathSE reviewer to be unsure what you are asking.

Comment: As a separate criticism of your posting, ask yourself how difficult it is for a mathSE reviewer to examine your posting, as it is currently presented.  The paragraph following "What I tried is the following:" is very poorly presented, and badly needs judicious line breaks, which can be done via `<br>`.  Also, please use  
[MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to present any math in your current or future questions.

Comment: I voted to close because the issue of whether $5$ is a valid choice for the second player is unresolved.  If it is not an allowed choice then the equal likelihood for the second player is $1/7$ rather than $1/8$, whereas if it is a losing choice, then this needs to be counted as another way for the first person to "win".  The problem lacks clarity on this essential detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than dealing with multiplying probabilities and adding that way, let us instead deal with *counting* arguments... counting in an *organized* and *efficient* manner.

With first person choosing $0$, the second person has six valid options which are larger.  With first person choosing $1$ the second person has five valid options, and so on...

There are then $6+5+4+3$ valid cases we are interested in.

This is out of $4\times 8$ total equally likely cases.

The probability is then $\dfrac{6+5+4+3}{4\times 8} = \dfrac{18}{32}= \dfrac{9}{16}=0.5+\dfrac{1}{16}= 0.5625$, all arithmetic able to be done mentally.

Answer (score 0):

@JMoravitz gave you a solution , but i want to give another method to show you a trick to get rid of brutal force.

First of all our our sample space is all possible matches such that $(2,5),(0,7)$ etc. There are $4 \times 8 =32$ ways to do it. You can think it like cartesian products of these two sets.

However , we do no not want the cases where the second takes $5$ and the first takes one of $4,6,7$. According to this information , the sample set of second person is $\{0,1,2,3,4,6,7\}$. We have $7$ elements here. Lets choose $2$ elements from this set by $C(7,2)=21$ ways , and say that the least of these selected two numbers belongs to the first person.For example , if we chose $(0,4)$ in combination , then the zero will automatically go to the first person because of the bijection.

However ,realize that some of these $21$ possible combination will include some unwanted cases such as $(4,7)$ .So , we must subtract these unwante cases where the first person takes the values greater than $3$,i.e, both person choose their numbers from $\{4,6,7\}$. We can do it such that $C(3,2)=3$

So , $$\frac{21-3}{32}=0.5625$$